# ReactJS - JSS - createUseStyles - how to generate inline style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I am using ReactJS/NextJS and

```
import { createUseStyles } from 'react-jss'
```

to generate CSS-in-JS. Is there a way to use `react-jss` to generate inline CSS?

I would like to add

```
const styles = ....

...
<Head><style>{styles}</style></Head>
```

to all my components.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I can see some potential here: https://cssinjs.org/react-jss?v=v10.7.1#server-side-rendering

But I am not sure how to use the SheetsRegistry with NextJs and serveless deployment. I tried adding it to the `_app.js` but did not work.

EDIT:

Following this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-react-jss/pages , I have been able to make progress.

The new problem is that now ALL OF THE CSS is in the HTML inline. I am using SSR, wouldn't it be possible to only add the CSS of the component involved in this page ?

Comment: I’d recommend [styled-jsx](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-jsx) instead as it pretty much covers what you want (also made by Vercel for NextJS).

Comment: @MattCarlotta , I tried this but I don't like it as much as the plain json with `react-jss`. With `react-jss` I can build fancier methods to build the CSS and the IDE deal with it much better.